# Can anyone spot the error that i am making?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic

All test case is running successfully except one which is **in1To10(9, true) → false.**

Question:

> Given a number n, return true if n is in the range 1..10,
>   inclusive. Unless outsideMode is true, in which case return true if
>   the number is less or equal to 1, or greater or equal to 10.

in1To10(5, false) → true
in1To10(11, false) → false
in1To10(11, true) → true

My Solution:-

```
public boolean in1To10(int n, boolean outsideMode) {
  if(n>=1&&n<=10){
    return true;
  }
 else if(outsideMode==true&&(n<=1||n>=10)){
    return true;
  }else
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can spot the error. You should find it yourself, using a debugger. That will help you to solve such simple bugs on your own. See [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned in problem the return boolean value is based on **boolean value of outsideMode** and the **range (1-10)** value

But in your program the first return statement value is decided by only the range criteria you did't test the boolean value of outsideMode.

**1. Solution :**
Either swap the second if(condition) with first if(condition)

```
public boolean in1To10(int n, boolean outsideMode) {
  if((outsideMode==false)&&(n>=1&&n<=10)){
    return true;
  }
 else if(outsideMode==true&&(n<=1||n>=10)){
    return true;
  }else
  return false;
}
```

**2.Solution:**
include the outsideMode with first if(condition) same like second if(condition)

```
public boolean in1To10(int n, boolean outsideMode) {
  if(outsideMode==true&&(n<=1||n>=10)){
    return true;
  }
 else if(n>=1&&n<=10){
    return true;
  }else
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `outsideMode` is a boolean so just writte `outisdeMode&&(n<=1||n>=10)`

Your error is that

```
  if(n>=1&&n<=10){
    return true;
  }
```

Will be executed befor

```
else if(outsideMode==true&&(n<=1||n>=10))
```

Because 9  >= 1 && 9 <= 10 which means that it will return true

Swap them and you will be fine

```
public boolean in1To10(int n, boolean outsideMode) {
  if(outsideMode&&(n<=1||n>=10)){
    return true;
  }
 else if(!outsideMode&&n>=1&&n<=10){
    return true;
  }else
  return false;
}
```

Comment: It's not working and still, one case is getting failed.

Comment: Could you provide more inside on the  failed case?   @ritesh_ratn

Comment: This test case is getting failed-> in1To10(9, true). The expected output is 'false' but your code is running 'true' for this case.

Comment: retry it now it should be fixed. [Code has been tested here](https://repl.it/@BalGu/LightgrayOverjoyedQueryplan)

Comment: @ritesh_ratn under the upvote button,(upper left next to this answer). (Where currently it says 0 and has one up arrow and one down arrow) It currently is gray. Marking it as resolved will show it green.(By clicking on it)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "all test cases are running successfully", that is rather misleading since you have too few test cases.

For each interesting integer comparison you need 2 test cases: one in which the comparison succeeds and one in which it fails. As test data you should pick the two integers that make the difference. For example, if the condition is `n > 10`, you should use 10 and 11 as test data.

In your scenario you have a boolean, and in each case of that boolean you have two integer conditions. Altogether, that makes `2 * 2 * 2 = 8` test cases. That is much more than the 3 test cases that you currently have, but it's necessary.

By testing your code systematically you will produce more reliable code than without these tests, even if it takes some time. But in return you get more confidence in the code, and that is worth it.

Further reading: test coverage, condition coverage.